# Pyserial reads data but does not write

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a [Digi Transport WR41](http://www.digi.com/support/productdetail?pid=5500&type=documentation) cellular router that runs a it's own proprietary operating system and a Python 2.6 interpreter. The router has a serial port (RJ45) that I've connected to a serial port (DB9) on a Windows 7 PC. The cable wiring is a straight through configuration.

On the PC, I've installed `RealTerm Serial Capture program` and connected it to `COM1`.

I want to be able to read/write data through the serial connection using `python` (and `pyserial`).

My python script is very very basic:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port=0, baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, timeout=1)
ser.write(‘hello world’)
#ser.read(1000)
```

When I send data from `RealTerm`, I can read it just fine in python via `ser.read(1000)`. This works all day long.

However, when I try to send data from python via `ser.write('hello world')`, I am unable to see it in `RealTerm`.

Thinking it might be a `RealTerm` issue, I tried other emulator/capture programs on the PC: [TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en) and [Serial Port Monitor 6](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/) (by Eltima), but I never saw the data show up.

Serial Port Monitor 6 was the only program to show some sort activity, but I still never saw my data. I don't know enough about serial communication to make any sense of the output, but here is an excerpt:

```
[19/02/2015 07:58:21] 
435 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL - Request operates a serial port (COM1) 
    STATUS_SUCCESS 
        IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK - Request is used to wait for the occurrence of any wait event specified by using an IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK request 
            Mask - 0x00000010 (EV_DSR) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[19/02/2015 07:58:21] 
437 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL - Request operates a serial port (COM1) 
    STATUS_SUCCESS 
        IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_WAIT_MASK - Request returns the event wait mask that is currently set on a COM port 
            Mask - 0x00000119 (EV_CTS | EV_DSR | EV_RING | EV_RXCHAR) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[19/02/2015 07:58:21] 
439 IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL - Request operates a serial port (COM1) 
    STATUS_SUCCESS 
        IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_MODEMSTATUS - Request updates the modem status, and returns the value of the modem status register before the update 
            Modem Status - 0x00000080 (MS_RLSD_ON) 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The router has a counter for `Bytes Sent`. Every time I call `ser.write('hello world')`, I see it increment by the correct number of bytes.

I've looked at two similar issues on SO:

- [pySerial sends ASCII data but recieving device does not respond to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654031/pyserial-sends-ascii-data-but-recieving-device-does-not-respond-to-it)
- [PySerial can read but not write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476536/pyserial-can-read-but-not-write)

I've verified that the device, RealTerm and the python code have consistent settings for the baudrate, parity, stopbits, control flow, etc.

Any other ideas why serial communication with pyserial would only work one way? Why would reads be allowed but not writes?

Answer (score 0):

> When I send data from RealTerm, I can read it just fine in python via ser.read(1000). This works all day long.
>
> However, when I try to send data from python via ser.write('hello world'), I am unable to see it in RealTerm.

Are you sure that you can send 'hello world' maybe this is just filtered ?
Did you try with another command or at least another encoding format?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by filtered? As far as encoding format, do you mean something like: ser.write('hello world'.encode(utf-8))?

Comment: By filtered i mean, on my software, if i receive a frame that i don't want i just drop it, maybe the router do the same thing.

By encoding (depend of your router, sorry didn't read the doc).Still on my soft (monitoring with emdebbed system), i can't send string like that, i have to convert them to Ascii code / Hex / Decimal

Also you can check if the serial port is "writable" that way :

Comment: `code`
def wait_until_connection_available(self, timeout):
        while ((not self.serial_connection) or (not self.serial_connection.writable) or (not self.serial_connection.readable)) and timeout > 0:
            timeout -= 10
            time.sleep(.010)
        if timeout == 0:
            print('Connection not available : timeout') 

`code`

To not use read(1000) you can :

`code`
  data += self.serial_connection.read(
                    self.serial_connection.inWaiting())
`code`

Comment: I tried sending a modbus instruction (which is ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish) - something like: modbus_packet = struct.pack(">HHHBBHH", TRANSACTION_ID, PROTOCOL_ID, LENGTH, UNIT_ID, FUNC_CODE, START_ADDR, QUANTITY) followed by ser.write(modbus_packet). TRANSACTION_ID, PROTOCOL_ID, etc. are all hex. I still did not receive the message in RealTerm.

Comment: Is it possible (I know it's unlikely) you need to end with a line terminator? what if you write "hello world\n" to the port?